# Ant design Form.list usage with pre filled data?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ant-design-pro

I've been using ant design for a while and needed the Form.list for a feature.
I can implement the entire workflow, but can't implement a pre filled form items in the list.

```
const user = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Can we have 3 form items in Form.list pre filled with the user array as an example?
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly and apparently there is no way to it using the Form.item. You can check out dynamic form api and use it to create your own dynamic fields. I will post my solution for it when i have it. Until then, any feedback are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Form.Item` as placeholder in `Form.List` to keep per key in data you can get, just like

```
<Form.Item name={[name, 'key']}>
 <Input style={{ display: 'none' }}/>
</Form.Item>
```

Then you can use `form.getFieldValue` to get it.

Comment: Please do not upload images of code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Form.List
        name="option_details"
        initialValue={[
          { first: "", last: "" },
          { first: "", last: "" },
          { first: "", last: "" },
        ]}
      >
```

the initial values key seems to be that way to accomplish this. Im using the same thing in my form and will pre-populate the values from a database call.